# Define Enum with strong-typedef CPP

Tags: c++, enums, typedef, strongly-typed-enum

While defining a network-message struct:

1. Want to hold the Op field as an Enum (so to limit the allowed values).
2. Need to keep all fields as unsigned, and the Op specifically to be uint32_t.

Is there a way to combine these requirements?
something like:
typedef enum Op : uint32_t {save = 100, retrieve = 101, delete = 200};

Comment: Mostly want to narrow the allowed valus --> Enum ---> string. Will appreciate other suggestions. Thank you.




http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0138r2.pdf

Comment: Not clear what you want, if its an enum with a specific type then you have it on C++11 like this: ```enum name : type { enumerator = constexpr , enumerator = constexpr , ... }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"100" "101" "200`

Well, I don't quite understand what these strings mean? Your question is not very clear to me.

It sounds like what you want is `enum class` ([Scoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)).

```
enum class Op : uint32_t
{
    _100 = 100,
    _101 = 101,
    _200 = 200
};
```

> limit the allowed values

Yes.

> Need to keep all fields as unsigned, and the Op specifically to be uint32_t.

Yes.

You should name these enumerators something meaningful, rather than the same as the value.

---

According to your edited post:

```
enum class Op : uint32_t
{
    save = 100,
    retrieve = 101,
    delete_ = 200
};
```